# BeautifulSoup couldn't scrape values from table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I scrape [this Taiwanese stock website](http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/fibest.jsp?stock=2412) with beautifulsoup on Python.
I can see the html code in my Chrome as follows, but how can I get the text inside the `<td>`?

```
<td id="2412_b4" align="center" style="color: rgb(16, 80, 16);">97.40</td>
```

When I use Python to get the text inside the 
I got the result like this:

```
<td align="center" id="2412_b4">-</td>
```

My code is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2, sys
#from BeautifulSoup import beautifulsoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import requests
#from lxml import html


site= "http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/fibest.jsp?stock=2412"
hdr = {
  'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.130 Safari/537.36',
  'Accept-Language':'zh_tw',
  'Cookie':'JSESSIONID=761ED2DA50CCC87E053877524B1827D7',
  'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Cache-Control':'max-age=0',
  'Accept-Encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch'
}

req = requests.get(site, headers = hdr, verify = False)

#page = urllib2.urlopen(req)

soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"html.parser")


T = soup.findAll('tbody', {'id':'hor-minimalist-tb'})
for name in T:
  print name.text
```

Please tell me how can I get the text inside the

---

UPDATE: I tried the tutorial that @Anand S Kumar gave me. My edited code is
:

```
import sys  
from PyQt4.QtGui import *  
from PyQt4.QtCore import *  
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *  
from lxml import html 

#Take this class for granted.Just use result of rendering.
class Render(QWebPage):  
  def __init__(self, url):  
    self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
    QWebPage.__init__(self)  
    self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
    self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
    self.app.exec_()  
  
  def _loadFinished(self, result):  
    self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
    self.app.quit()


url = "http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/fibest.jsp?stock=2412"    
#url = 'http://pycoders.com/archive/'  
r = Render(url)  
result = r.frame.toHtml()
#QString should be converted to string before processed by lxml
formatted_result = str(result.toAscii())

#Next build lxml tree from formatted_result
tree = html.fromstring(formatted_result)

#Now using correct Xpath we are fetching URL of archives
archive_links = tree.xpath('//tbody[@id="hor-minimalist-tb"]/tr/td/text()')
print archive_links
```

It still doesn't work for me. The values inside are still:

Comment: This is yet another duplicate question about trying to scrape when the data is in JS, not HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Like already said in the other answer, the actual data in the page is javascript rendered/ajax rendered.

If you use `view page source` in chrome for the page, you will see the raw html source for the component you are checking as -

```
    <tbody id="hor-minimalist-tb">
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="color:#000000">-</td>
        <td align="center">-</td>
        <td id="2412_a4" align="center">-</td>
        <td id="2412_f4" align="center" style="color:#000000">-</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="color:#000000">-</td>
        <td align="center">-</td>
        <td id="2412_a3" align="center">-</td>
        <td id="2412_f3" align="center" style="color:#000000">-</td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td align="center" style="color:#000000">-</td>
        <td align="center">-</td>
        <td id="2412_a2" align="center">-</td>
        <td id="2412_f2" align="center" style="color:#000000">-</td>
      </tr> 
      .
      .
    </tbody>
```

When you do -

```
 req = requests.get(site, headers = hdr, verify = False)
```

`req.text` contains the raw html source of the page, not the javascript rendered DOM . That is why you are getting the result from BeautifulSoup as you are getting.

For javascript rendered pages, you can follow the tutorial at  - https://impythonist.wordpress.com/2015/01/06/ultimate-guide-for-scraping-javascript-rendered-web-pages/ (The code there is for lxml, but can easily be adapted for BeautifulSoup). It uses the QT Web Kit library. (Disclaimer : That is not my tutorial/content )

Comment: Thanks you tutorial. but it can't work. the value still are - 
I edit my question and put new code.

Answer (score 0):

The real data are loaded via Ajax, that's why BeautifulSoup can only get the placeholder.

To monitor the ajax requests, you can using tools like Chrome developer tools.

Answer (score 0):

In cases likes this where the data is not in the HTML source, it should came from somewhere. So if you check HTTP connections issued by the site you will find that the data is being fetched from the website API:

```
http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/api/getStockInfo.jsp?ex_ch=tse_2412.tw&json=1&delay=0&_=1438929024846
```

Example of the json:

```
{
  "msgArray": [
    {
      "ts": "0",
      "tk0": "2412.tw_tse_20150807_B_9999301124",
      "tk1": "2412.tw_tse_20150807_B_9999283564",
      "oa": "98.00",
      "ob": "97.90",
      "tlong": "1438928700000",
      "f": "1584_141_122_674_83_",
      "ot": "14:25:00",
      "ex": "tse",
      "g": "22_130_76_108_106_",
      "ov": "-",
  .
  .
  .
  .
}
```

However when you want to direct access to the URL. You need to use valid cookies. but if you try to

```
s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/fibest.jsp?stock=2412")
```

You will get `<Response [500]>`
And by checking the response code you will find that you need to send `Accept-Language` cookies.

```
r = s.get("http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/fibest.jsp?stock=2412", headers = {"Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.5"})
```

Comment: How do you get this?
http://mis.twse.com.tw/stock/api/getStockInfo.jsp?ex_ch=tse_2412.tw&json=1&delay=0&_=1438929024846

Comment: @RapunzelKath You could use [HTTPFox](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwj_mOGauZbHAhWBFj4KHaCQAE4&url=https%3A%2F%2Faddons.mozilla.org%2Fen-us%2Ffirefox%2Faddon%2Fhttpfox%2F&ei=AF7EVf-YE4Gt-AGgoYLwBA&usg=AFQjCNFkDPAB1iOsbJg-CPNqZLscXZlFPA&sig2=A8rKekosbpHrLHMx_fuFGw&bvm=bv.99804247,d.cWw)

Comment: Thank you. But I don't understand how to use this on my code. How can I fetch the data in Python?